# How do I quickly hide all layers except selected one?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, shortcuts

In Photoshop, how does all layers in the project are hide except selected one..for example if there is 10 layers are there in my project. i need one layer should be visible and remaining 9 layers should hide ..is their any shortcut to do this

Thanks very much for any help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> in Windows or <kbd>Option</kbd> on OS X, then click the layer visibility icon. Repeating this action will revert the visibility.

[image]